# Jackson ObjectMapper from MongoDB BSON

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson, bson

I got a JSON that I serialize to a MongoDB `BasicDBObject` and insert it into the DB:

```
    String serialized = "";
    try {
        serialized = OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(customEx.getOut().getBody());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    collection.update(upsertQuery, BasicDBObject.parse(serialized), true, false);
```

On reading the `DBObject` from the DB I want to convert it to a POJO using the `ObjectMappers'` `readValue()` with a given class:

```
    public static <T> T fromDB(DBObject o, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(o.toString(), clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The class I want to convert it to is generated from an xsd sheme and also contains `timestamps`/`long` values as following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ItemType")
public class ItemType {

@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
[...]
```

However this worked fine for older Java MongoDB versions. Now the long values are serialized as BSON looking like this:

```
"date": {
    "$numberLong": "1551172199214"
}
```

When I try to deserialize this using jacksons `ObjectMapper` I get

> Cannot deserialize instance of `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` out of START_OBJECT token

The reason for this is clear to me because the long value is in an own BSON - `Style` object.

So far I already tried using `BsonDocument` like this:

```
public static <T> T fromDB(DBObject o, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        BsonDocument parse = BsonDocument.parse(o.toString());
        return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(parse.toJson(), clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But that still does not convert the BSON parts to JSON.

Is there any way to deserialize the BSON to a given Class using Jacksons `ObjectMapper`?
Or just convert it to a `DBObject` without using BSON parts?

Comment: Try using MongoJack to map the Json (Bson) from MongoDB to your objects

Comment: Example:
ObjectMapper myObjectMapper = ...
MongoJackModule.configure(myObjectMapper);
JacksonDBCollection<BlogPost, String> coll = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(DBCollection dbCollection, BlogPost.class,
        String.class, myObjectMapper); 
More details: https://mongojack.org/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to configure the `ObjectMapper` to deserialize the `XMLGregorianCalendar` differently:

```
public class XMLGregorianCalendarDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<XMLGregorianCalendar> {
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public XMLGregorianCalendar deserialize(
    JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
  Map<String, String> bsonStringAsMap =
      objectMapper.readValue(
          jsonParser.readValueAsTree().toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});

  String timestampString = bsonStringAsMap.get("$numberLong");
  if (timestampString != null && !timestampString.isEmpty()) {
    long timestamp = Long.parseLong(timestampString);
    Date date = new Date(timestamp);
    GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);
    return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
  }
  return null;
  }
}
```

Then you can annotate the field with this and deserialize as you have been:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=XMLGregorianCalendarDeserializer.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If calendar field is wrapped we need to unwrap it. We can extend already implemented `CoreXMLDeserializers.GregorianCalendarDeserializer`:

```
class XmlGregorianCalendarDeserializer extends CoreXMLDeserializers.GregorianCalendarDeserializer {

    @Override
    public XMLGregorianCalendar deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException {
        jp.nextToken(); // Skip FIELD_NAME
        jp.nextToken(); // Skip VALUE_STRING

        XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = super.deserialize(jp, ctxt);

        jp.nextToken(); // Skip END_OBJECT

        return calendar;
    }
}
```

If `XMLGregorianCalendar` is always wrapped we can register this deserialiser using `SimpleModule`. See below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.CoreXMLDeserializers;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule wrappedCalendarModule = new SimpleModule();
        wrappedCalendarModule.addDeserializer(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, new XmlGregorianCalendarDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(wrappedCalendarModule);
        String json = "{\n"
            + "   \"date\":{\n"
            + "      \"$numberLong\":\"1551172199214\"\n"
            + "   },\n"
            + "   \"name\":\"Rick\"\n"
            + "}";
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class));
    }
}

class Wrapper {

    private XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    private String name;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Wrapper{date=2019-02-26T09:09:59.214Z, name='Rick'}
```